# Cydia Substrate Tweak - How to get directory from the hooked application (classname)

Tags: ios, mobile, theos, cydia

Im still learning to make a tweak for an app and I need to edit the plist file inside the app folder.

I already search here and google but still got nothing.

So, my question is :

1. How to get the app folder location using Cydia Substrate?
2. How to edit plist file using Cydia Substrate?

Thanks and Regards..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [NSBundle mainBundle],its properties are what you need.
   2.NSDictionary or NSArray.
   Basically these parts are the same as standard iOS Development